# Background Iteration of BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I need a specific kind of queue with very good performance characteristics so I'm needing to roll my own (luckily it's only a few lines of code).

So I am using a LinkedBlockingQueue to back the pool since unlike ArrayBlockingQueue it has separate take and put locks.

Occasionally I need to iterate through the whole pool to keep pooled sockets alive (because the server I'm using has an idle client timeout).

I can't really figure out a great way to do this. What I'd LIKE to do is have an iterator that allows me to remove a pooled object from the queue if it exists, run the keep-alive ping, and then return it. But the LinkedBlockingQueue iterator doesn't allow me to keep the element "removed" after calling #next.

The only solution I see (which I don't like) is to remove all items in the pool with #drainTo and just return each one as it is processed. This is what I'm doing now. I don't want to introduce new locks.

I suppose I could alternative ensure it the queue is FIFO, get the queue count at the time of the iteration and just #poll each element while the count >= 0 or #poll returns null.

Is there a solution I'm missing that will be efficient or not require FIFO?

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance without introducing new locks and not using the `drainTo` is simply iterating over the Queue like a collection.  **Note** The iterated element you are currently looking at may have been removed from the queue, so you would possibly need additional synchronization.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#iterator()

> The returned iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Comment: The problem with this is that the element will still be available in the queue after I call #next and while I perform validation. I don't want the element to be available until validation is complete. Hence using #drainTo or #poll.

Comment: @user1888440 If that's the case, drainTo my be your best option